# Hibernate get entity by non-primary key and update it + Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I retrieve an object using its id and I change its properties and update it, everything work fine but when I get my objects using their name + version and update them, none of the changes save in the database. Could you please someone let me know what is the problem?!

// Get by id

```
public PdfDocument get(Long id) {
    return (PdfDocument) session().get(PdfDocument.class, id);
}
```

// Get by name + version

```
public PdfDocument get(String name, int version) {
    Criteria criteria = session().createCriteria(PdfDocument.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("version", version));
    return ((PdfDocument) criteria.uniqueResult()) ;
}
```

// update

```
public void update(PdfDocument PdfDocument) {
    session().saveOrUpdate(PdfDocument);
}
```

Comment: Did the `get(name, version)` method return a `PdfDocument `object or null?

Answer (score 0):

May be criteria returning a different entity than your expecting one. Check the id of returned entity and the expected one.